# what is the best way to store an array in mysql ?

Tags: mysql, arrays

i have a table users
every user have list of favorites.
and user can change , delete or add to the favorites

Comment: depends what is your array actually, you may need to normalize your table and a new array_table with reference to array_table in previous table instead a flat field. Or it may required to add multiple columns in same table instead a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalizing a table is usually better than storing serialised results, even though the later is tempting.

In order to normalize the data create a new table `favourites'. This table should have:

- a field with a unique ID (id) - this should be the primary key and auto increment.
- a field user id which holds the ID of the user of the favourite (I call it user_id for the purpose of this example) - this field should be an index.
- a field that identifies the favourite's value. I would assume in your case that's probably a URL (I call it value).

The code:

```
CREATE TABLE favourites
(
    `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(10),
    `value` varchar(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`)
);
```

Comment: but like that  i will  more heavy  than a flat field

Comment: Not really - You just move the data and its schema from the application into the database, that's what databases are made for. If - as according to your question - you want to be able to change, delete and add them then even more so. It is also more extendible... think about sorting them or adding a name or title for them. Much easier to apply to a table than to a serialised data set that exists in every record.